# Running functions siultaneoulsy in python

Tags: python, multithreading, module, process, global

I am making a small program in which I need a few functions to check for something in the background.

I used module threading and all those functions indeed run simultaneously and everything works perfectly until I start adding more functions. As the threading module makes new threads, they all stay within the same process, so when I add more, they start slowing each other down.

The problem is not with the CPU as it's utilization never reaches 100% (`i5-4460`). I also tried the multiprocessing module which creates a new process for function, but then it seems that variables can't be shared between different processes or I don't know how. (newly started process for each function seems to take existing variables with itself, but my main program cannot access any of the changes that function in the separate process makes or even new variables it creates)

I tried using the `global` keyword but it seems to have no effect in multiprocessing as it does in threading.

How could I solve this problem?

I am pretty sure that I have to create new processes for those background functions but I need to get some feedback from them and that part I don't know to solve.

Comment: Show the code that demonstrates the problem to be solved.

Comment: I'm gonna watch some tutorials on Multiprocessing, hope I will find answer there, will post here if I do.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html has small examples, including how to share variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using multiprocessing Value

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you problem, you need to cap the number of "processors".

What I usually do in those kind of situation is spawning a fixed (thus configurable by parameter) number of processors (i.e. thread or process) I call workers.

Then I use a shared tasks queue (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) to send the worker their job to do and I use another shared queue where they can put their results.

Workers can even populate the tasks queue so you add new tasks from the worker if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation at [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) for "*threading — Thread-based parallelism*" it clearly states:

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only **one thread can execute Python code at once** (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). **If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.** However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

[Python Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing)

Comment: I understand that, but how do I exchange information between processes (how do I send simple True or False to my main program from started process). I've seen some ways in documentation on Multiprocessing, but what is the best/simplest way to do that.